# Why does $\left(1+ 1/k\right)^k$ converge to $e$ as $k \to\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

I came across this when learning about sequences and series. No one proved it to me tho! Is there a link anywhere? Or would it be beyond what I know? (First term of analysis)

Comment: Define $e{{{}}}$.

Comment: You need to realise that it is a definition, we simply define $e$ as this limit. It is easy to prove that the sequence is increasing and bounded above, I'll try to find a link.

Comment: It's a bit cheating, there are other definitions of $e$, for example $\int_1^e \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}=1$.

Comment: Take the exponential and natural logarithm together with this limit and you should get your answer nicely.

Comment: @EricAm, some people use this as the definition. The interesting part then would be to show that $e=\exp(1)$, where $\exp'=\exp$, $\exp(0)=1$. But it would be good to know what user116695's definition is.

Comment: These close-as-off-topic votes are absurd!

Comment: @EricAm : What one takes to be a definition is often only a matter of convention, and this particular characterization of $e$ is not always taken to be the definition.  Even if it were, there would be an excellent question: Why should one single out the particular number defined that way for so much special attention?

Answer (score 5):

Of course, this depends on how you define $e$. Here is something that would convince a calculus student.

Taking logs we have:
$\log((1 + \frac{1}{k})^k) = k \log(1 + \frac{1}{k})$

So we can take this limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$ using l'hospitals rule.

$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} k \log(1 + \frac{1}{k}) = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log(1 + \frac{1}{k})}{\frac{1}{k}} = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{-\frac{1}{k^2 + k}}{-\frac{1}{k^2}} = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{k^2}{k^2 + k} = 1$$

Hence, using continuity of the function $e^x$, we conclude that

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} (1 + \frac{1}{k})^k = e^1 = e$$

Comment: Where you apply l'Hopital, one can just as well use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Thanks! I didn't think of it while writing, but I completely agree.

Comment: But how do we know that $\ln'x=\dfrac1x$ ? Are you sure this proof isn't cyclical ?

Comment: @Lucian I too was a bit skeptical of this answer, but I think this is coming from the perspective of "supposing that $e$ exists, with all the properties that are usually taught in a calculus course ($e^x$ is its own derivative, etc.), show that $(1+1/n)^n \to e$."

Comment: @Lucian, it all depends on what the definitions are that one starts with. One could define $\exp$ as a power series, show  $\exp'=\exp$, $\exp(0)=1$ and also $\exp(a+b)=\exp a\cdot \exp b$, then define $e=\exp(1)$ and $\ln$ via $\ln(\exp(x))=x$.

Comment: @blf Yes, this is the perspective I was going for!

Answer (score 2):

<s>Usually</s> Sometimes, $e$ is [*defined*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) to be $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n$. What might need to be proved is that that limit exists.

Incidentally, this can be proved as well
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$$

I think a discussion of these things can be found in [Rudin's PMA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007054235X).

Comment: It's odd. Every book that I remember defined $e$ as $$e = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}.$$ In other parts of the world, the limit of $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ seems more prevalent. I wonder what determines which definition is commonly used where.

Comment: I disagree with the word "usually".  I'd agree if it said "sometimes".

Answer (score 0):

It's like calculating limit of function $\lim_{x\to \infty}(1+\frac1x)^x$

This is of the the form $1^{\infty}$.

So $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x = e^{\lim_{x\to\infty}((1+\frac1x)-1)(x)}$$

$$= e^1$$

$$= e$$